# XML or HTML? Help needed

Tags: html, xml

I am new to coding. I got a file called index.html. The first 2 lines in it are given below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Is it an html or xml file?

Comment: update your Question please !!

Comment: I don't see any lines but since it has an .html extension I dare to assume it's an html file

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 defines an XML serialisation. Previously, XHTML 1 defined an implementation of HTML 4 in XML.

It is XML. It is also either HTML or XHTML.

Answer (score -1):

Nice Question, First of all the first line is pure XML declaration[XML Declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048(v=vs.110).aspx), the second line is of html, and it contains meta data.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all. I am trying to convert an MS Word document to ePub using Calibre tool. The concerned document is created by Calibre. Now in the epub,the headings and images are not coming in the center(when I test with different epub readers).

Comment: Trying to correct it. I believe it has to mentioned in the code that the alignment of these has to be in the center.  If I share the code, can you help with it? Is it possible that I can paste teh code here?

Comment: Actually i don't have any knowledge about Calibre tool, but yes it is indeed possible that you can post your code in another question.